# Auto home issue on ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis

I own a Comgrow Creality Ender 3 3D Printer Aluminum DIY with Resume Print 220x220x250mm

I am a newbie and last night finally got a halfway decent print, but tonight I went to Auto Home it and it just keeps trying to move down, down down even though it physically can't go any lower. The z-axis just keeps trying to spin down. The long threaded metal rod just keeps turning like it needs to keep moving down. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your z-stop isn't engaging when it's supposed to. The z-axis end stop should be located at the left of the build plate on the z-axis column. When the gantry (with the printhead) comes down, it should contact that. If it doesn't contact it, or if the end stop isn't functioning (isn't sending the signal to stop), the z-axis will just continue to try and go down. Check to ensure it touches where  you want it to touch, and if it is, then check the operation of the end stop. You can do that with a multimeter set to ohms. Just detach the wiring from the main board, place your two multimeter leads on either wire end, then click the end stop. it should go from no continuity to full continuity when you hear the end stop click.

EDIT: The endstop should look something like this:

[image: Image pulled from https://images.monoprice.com]

Comment: Note:  The Z-stop is mounted on the outside of the left pillar.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - Thanks for the clarification ... I was having an issue coming up with the "proper" term :o)